# Loop in R not working for replacing dashes as null values

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, na

The loop below does not change my data but the print command works fine.
Can anyone point out my mistake in the replace loop command?

```
my_months <- c("jan" , "feb", "mar" , "april" , "may" , "june" , "july" , "aug" , "sep" , "oct" , "nov" , "dec")

for (month in my_months){
  print(paste("The month is", month))
  cleanest_data_2009$wireless_data_month_09[ cleanest_data_2009$wireless_data_month_09=="-" ] = NA       #replaces columns with pure "-" entries with a NA}
```

The error I get is -

```
Error in `*tmp*`[[nm]] : no such index at level 2
```

The data is added below - it contains 12 dataframes (names after months like *wireless_data_jan_09*, *wireless_data_feb_09*,...) within a list (  **cleanest_data_2009** ).

```
list(wireless_data_jan_09 = structure(list(Circle = c("Andaman & Nocobar", 
"A.P.", "Assam", "Bihar", "Chennai", "Chhatisgarh", "Delhi", 
"Gujarat", "H.P.", "Haryana", "J & K", "Jharkhand", "Karnataka", 
"Kerala", "Kolkata", "M.P.", "Maharashtra", "Mumbai", "North East-I", 
"North East-\r\nII", "Orissa", "Punjab", "Rajasthan", "T.N.", 
"U.P.(E)", "U.P.(W)", "Uttaranchal", "W.B."), `Vodafone Essar` = c("-", 
"3665593", "90720", "328444", "1508317", "-", "3919598", "7603362", 
"17371", "2082198", "-", "-", "3482124", "2900940", "2608970", 
"175337", "4226327", "4234006", "73205", "-", "233249", "2081484", 
"4738670", "4833724", "6090871", "4091105", "-", "4354409"), 
    Spice = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
    "-", "-", "1572915", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
    "2379192", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), BSNL = c("75011", 
    "3145768", "902820", "1882998", "1060042", "877954", "-", 
    "2555228", "798388", "1499021", "931577", "764799", "2435163", 
    "2957522", "1276117", "2060146", "3709924", "-", "323203", 
    "355962", "1429714", "2668042", "2991453", "3081565", "5597426", 
    "1698661", "767273", "1738713")), row.names = 3:30, class = "data.frame"), 
    wireless_data_feb_09 = structure(list(Circle = c("Andaman & Nocobar", 
    "A.P.", "Assam", "Bihar", "Chennai", "Chhatisgarh", "Delhi", 
    "Gujarat", "H.P.", "Haryana", "J & K", "Jharkhand", "Karnataka", 
    "Kerala", "Kolkata", "M.P.", "Maharashtra", "Mumbai", "North East-I", 
    "North East-\r\nII", "Orissa", "Punjab", "Rajasthan", "T.N.", 
    "U.P.(E)", "U.P.(W)", "Uttaranchal", "W.B."), `Vodafone Essar` = c("-", 
    "3806178", "121809", "601175", "1532394", "-", "4002549", 
    "7814248", "29756", "2150344", "-", "-", "3585428", "3001669", 
    "2720193", "255482", "4428389", "4303513", "107311", "-", 
    "284876", "2147163", "4888771", "5005095", "6323800", "4223429", 
    "-", "4587330"), Spice = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "1620929", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "2427574", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"
    ), `BPL Mobile` = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "2073184", "-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Idea = c("-", 
    "4944611", "-", "607458", "-", "-", "2401927", "3802544", 
    "135768", "1556767", "-", "-", "-", "4241565", "-", "4828687", 
    "7226734", "690913", "-", "-", "-", "-", "1206546", "-", 
    "1922428", "3904162", "-", "-"),  `Vodafone Essar` = c("4416028", 
    "273162", "1422240", "1626652", "4253878", "8606777", "70877", 
    "2351449", "109943", "4071322", "3474920", "3035964", "613735", 
    "5363034", "4582141", "273793", "632914", "2348146", "5555606", 
    "5702130", "7459534", "4801976", "5403377"), Spice = c("-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "1765742", "-", "-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "2554320", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"
    ), `Loop Mobile(BPL` = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "2305640", "-", "-", "-", 
    "-", "-", "-", "-", "-"), Idea = c("5463665", "-", "1454923", 
    "-", "2336208", "4200086", "159508", "1614431", "-", "-", 
    "4728033", "-", "5600628", "8000687", "940274", "-", "156905", 
    "-", "1337896", "64526", "2318149", "4392897", "-"), `Bharti BSNL` = c("3714654", "1005079", "3125544", 
    "1158894", "-", "2662688", "986778", "1937685", "945643", 
    "2977518", "3294945", "1624823", "3141374", "3974525", "-", 
    "848681", "1786037", "2996273", "3216472", "3768725", "6361985", 
    "2782080", "2054099")), row.names = 3:25, class = "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Why is the replacement line inside a for loop? The task it is performing only needs to be done once, and has nothing to do with the month being iterated. Also, your question is unanswerable without seeing the data you are using your code on.

Comment: I'm guessing your column names have the months built in, meaning that you have a column `cleanest_data_2009$wireless_data_jan_09`, and not `..._month_09`, is that right? It would help immensely to have a sample of your data, please [edit] your question and add the output from `dput(head(cleanest_data_2009))` into a code block. (Please make sure that the sample data has some `-` and some not-`-` values.)

Comment: Thoughts: (1) form your column name programmatically with `paste0`, as in `nm <- paste0("wireless_data_",month,"_09"]]; cleanest_data_2009[[nm]][cleanest_data_2009[[nm]]=="-"] <- NA`; (2) there are a couple of different dashes, some shorter/longer, you might change `=="-"` to `%in% c("-", "–", "—")` where the second and third are still single-characters (not repeated simple-dashes) and might be what you're seeing in your data. If the second/third dashes are not different (due to Stack text simplifying), then copy/paste them from the web, perhaps https://www.scribbr.com/language-rules/dashes/.

Comment: Also, note that `NA` (in your code) is not the same as `NULL` (in your title).

Comment: Should not be reopened: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73267625/loop-in-r-not-working-for-replacing-dashes-as-na-values